# The connection roles are not related

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

```
XrmServiceContext       xrmSvc      = null;
xrmSvc = new XrmServiceContext("http://mycrmwebdev/CRMDev")
Connection cnctn = xrmSvc.ConnectionSet.Where(c => c.ConnectionId == "3D2BC21F-6D8F-E211-9F0F-1CC1DE248972").First();

if (cnctn != null) {
    CrmEntityReference rec1RoleId = new CrmEntityReference {
        LogicalName = ConnectionRole.EntityLogicalName,
        Name = "Record1RoleId",
        Id = new Guid("B818399C-E766-E111-A1B1-00155D0A6B13")
    };

    CrmEntityReference rec2RoleId = new CrmEntityReference {
        LogicalName = ConnectionRole.EntityLogicalName,
        Name = "Record2RoleId",
        Id = new Guid("B818399C-E766-E111-A1B1-00155D0A6B13")
    };

    cnctn.Record1RoleId = rec1RoleId;
    cnctn.Record2RoleId = rec2RoleId;

    xrmSvc.UpdateObject(cnctn);

    //Error occurs here
    xrmSvc.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I try to save, I get an error "The connection roles are not related". I'm not seeing much regarding this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are reciprocal relationships in the Connections table in CRM, make sure to update just one record. CRM will handle updating the reciprocal record.